# Getting mean of columns that have missing (NA) values

Tags: r, dplyr

I have a dataframe containing 6 years of data. Each of those years have the same variables. I am trying to find the mean for each variable across 6 years. There are missing (NA) in each year for different rows. In this example, i am trying to get the mean for the headcount for girls over 6 years.

I have tried using mutate and the pipe function, but it doesn't seem to work. It is giving me strange results, by duplicating all my columns.

```
roughcopy2$headcount_girls_mean <- 

  roughcopy2 %>% 
  mutate(headcount_girls_mean=rowMeans(.[ , 
c("headcount_total_girls_rounded_1314","headcount_total_girls_rounded_1415", 
                               "headcount_total_girls_rounded_1516" , 
"headcount_total_girls_rounded_1617",
                               "headcount_total_girls_1718", 
"headcount_total_girls_1819")], na.rm=TRUE))
```

This code is duplicating all my columns for the dataframe, and adding "headcount_girls_mean." to each column name in the duplicated dataset. So my original dataset, i.e roughcopy2 has 150 columns. After I run the above, i get 300 columns, and the latter 150 are the same column headings at the former 150, but with a prefix of "headcount_girls_mean."

Comment: Please add a sample of your data with `dput`. Use `dput(head(roughcopy,n))`.

Comment: You should add a sample of data (or a representation of your data) as already mentioned by @NelsonGon. From what you are telling us, I believe you should use something like `gather()` from the `tidyr` library. Using `gather()` you can collapse your columns into key-value pairs, and then do the analysis on this "tidy" data frame.

Comment: Try reading this tutorial on `dplyr` and `mutate`. https://stat545.com/block010_dplyr-end-single-table.html I don't want to sound purist, but you're using `mutate` very wrongly.

Answer (score 1):

Using a imaginary sample of your data-frame:

```r
roughcopy2 <- data.frame("headcount_total_girls_rounded_1314"=c(1,4,2,4,8),
                          "headcount_total_girls_rounded_1415"=c(2, NA, 4, NA,8),
                          "headcount_total_girls_rounded_1516"=c(6,8,10,12,14),
                          "headcount_total_girls_rounded_1617"=c(4,5,5,3,2),
                          "headcount_total_girls_1718"=c(8,5,9,NA,2),
                          "headcount_total_girls_1819"=c(NA,2,4,7,3))
```

If you want the mean of the columns, you can simply:

```r
means <- as.numeric(colMeans(x=roughcopy2, na.rm = TRUE))
```

Although, if you want the mean across multiple columns values:

```r
roughcopy2 <- mutate(roughcopy2,
                     headcount_mean = rowMeans(select(roughcopy2, starts_with("headcount")),
                     na.rm = TRUE))
```

It should output (the others columns were omitted, but they're in the data-frame):

```r
  headcount_total_girls_1718 headcount_total_girls_1819 head_count_mean
1                          8                         NA            4.20
2                          5                          2            4.80
3                          9                          4            5.67
4                         NA                          7            6.50
5                          2                          3            6.17
```

You should put a sample of your original data-frame and general idea of what you expect as an output.

Answer (score 1):

I am still unsure about your intent, but if you would like a mean value per column, the following should work. This answer builds on from my comment and @Pedro_Henrique:

```
library(tidyverse)

roughcopy2 <- tibble("headcount_total_girls_rounded_1314"=c(1,4,2,4,8),
                          "headcount_total_girls_rounded_1415"=c(2, NA, 4, NA,8),
                          "headcount_total_girls_rounded_1516"=c(6,8,10,12,14),
                          "headcount_total_girls_rounded_1617"=c(4,5,5,3,2),
                          "headcount_total_girls_1718"=c(8,5,9,NA,2),
                          "headcount_total_girls_1819"=c(NA,2,4,7,3))

roughcopy2 %>%
  gather(headcount_year, count) %>%
  group_by(headcount_year) %>%
  summarise(mean_count = mean(count, na.rm = TRUE))
```

The resulting output:

```
# A tibble: 6 x 2
  headcount_year                     mean_count
  <chr>                                   <dbl>
1 headcount_total_girls_1718               6   
2 headcount_total_girls_1819               4   
3 headcount_total_girls_rounded_1314       3.8 
4 headcount_total_girls_rounded_1415       4.67
5 headcount_total_girls_rounded_1516      10   
6 headcount_total_girls_rounded_1617       3.8
```